# How can I establish an OpenVPN connection when connected to USG VLAN

Tags: openvpn, unifi

I'm using a USG for our business and our remote users connect to an internal VLAN by establishing a VPN connection. We host OpenVPN CE on one of our servers. The client is configured with a public IP and I have a NAT rule defined to forward VPN traffic over port 1194 to the VPN server's private IP. All of our remote users can connect as expected.

But we now have use case where office users connected to one of VLANs will need to establish a VPN connection in order to access systems that require this level of security. However I am unable to establish a VPN connection while connected to the VLAN -- it just hangs when attempting to connect. Essentially the client configuration is attempting to create a connection to a public IP that is Nat'd back to inside our network to the VPN server which is on a different VLAN.

I'm looking for advice on what to troubleshoot next

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `hairpin-nat enable` in your `/config/config.boot` file. Here's my reference. https://community.ui.com/questions/NAT-loopback-on-USG/ebc22213-b60f-433b-a367-fc5177933387

Comment: That was my first thought but I confirmed hairpin-nat was already enabled.